# How to join two table using GORM in many to many relationship?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have a many-to-many relationship between Products and Categories table. I want to retrieve all the products with their Categories.

```
type Product struct {
    ProductID       int          `gorm:"column:product_id;primary_key" json:"product_id"`
    Name            string       `gorm:"column:name" json:"name"`
    Description     string       `gorm:"column:description" json:"description"`
    Categories      []Category   `gorm:"many2many:product_category;foreignkey:product_id;association_foreignkey:category_id;association_jointable_foreignkey:category_id;jointable_foreignkey:product_id;"`
}

type Category struct {
    CategoryID   int         `gorm:"column:category_id;primary_key" json:"category_id"`
    Name         string      `gorm:"column:name" json:"name"`
    Description  null.String `gorm:"column:description" json:"description"`
    Products     []Product   `gorm:"many2many:product_category;foreignkey:category_id;association_foreignkey:product_id;association_jointable_foreignkey:product_id;jointable_foreignkey:category_id;"`
}
```

bellow code returns all the Products of categorie_id 3 but Categories slice of those products are empty

```
var products  []model.Product
cat := model.Category{}
s.db.First(&cat, "category_id = ?", 3)
err :=  s.db.Model(&cat).Related(&products, "Products").Error
```

I tried bellow code which returns nothing

```
var products  []model.Product
var cat       [] model.Category
err :=  s.db.Model(&cat).Related(&products, "Products").Error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution

```
products := []*model.Product{}
DB.Preload("Categories").Find(&products)
```

This will return all the products with their categories.

Comment: Do you know how to find products that contain a certain category?

Comment: @Ari  Code I added in the question contains ans of your question

var products  []model.Product
cat := model.Category{}
s.db.First(&cat, "category_id = ?", 3)
err :=  s.db.Model(&cat).Related(&products, "Products").Error